# Google sheet XPath scraping: copy currency exchange rate

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

From this URL `https://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert/?Amount=1&From=MYR&To=INR`   I want to copy the data into my google sheets.

in cell `A1` I have `https://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert/?Amount=1&From=MYR&To=INR`

in cell `A2` I have `=IMPORTXML(A1,"//span[@class='converterresult-toAmount']")`

I get output `N\A`

Can someone advise me how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, you can use the `GOOGLEFINANCE` formula to fetch the FX rates from Google Finance directly:

```
=index(GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:MYRINR","price",today(),1,"DAILY"),2,2)
```

This function will return the daily FX rate for MYR-INR for today.

See [GOOGLEFINANCE documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281?hl=en) for more details about the variations you can use to get more / different data.

I wrapped the Google Finance formula into an `INDEX` function to only get the rate (so you can use that in a multiplication to convert random amounts), as the `GOOGLEFINANCE` formula returns a table with dates and history by default.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, that won't be possible because the site is controlled by JavaScript and Google Sheets can't understand/import JS. you can test this simply by disabling JS for a given link and you will see a blank page:

[image]